# Declaration of the openness of a set

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = \{a, b\}$. A topology $T$ must contain $\emptyset$ and $X$.
> It may or may not contain $\{a\}$ or $\{b\}$. If they are both in $T$
> , this means that the two points are distinct and separate. If neither
> of them are in T , then the points are as close together as they could
> be (topologically indistinguishable). Finally, one could even declare
> $\{a\}$ to be open and not $\{b\}$.

Can someone explain the last statement? (Finally, one could even declare...) I don't understand why the openness of $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ can be declared (instead of being something that we determine from the definition of openness of a set)

Source: page 9 [here](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eauroux/131f19/Math_131_Notes_Beckham_Myers.pdf)

Comment: Determine from the definition? A topology is more or less up to you to define, or to declare, subject to some basic constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be used to a different context such as metric spaces where one could define $X$ to be open if for any $x\in X$ there is an open ball $B$ such that $x\in B\subset X$.  However when you are putting a topology on a set (no extra structure) there is no intrinsic definition of open set.

Rather you declare some collections of subsets of $X$ to be open. The choice is quite arbitrary, so there is a vast amount of topologies you can put on a generic set, but not completely so, it has to satisfy a few properties, listed in some of the other answers. There is no "symmetry" property like the one you mention: a point can be open and another one not.

In your case if $\{a\}$ is open then $X\setminus \{a\} = \{b\}$ has to be closed. Since sets are not doors, $\{b\}$ can also be open.  This leads to a case where every point, and thus every subset, is open, known in general as the discrete topology. The case where only $X$ and $\emptyset$ are open also makes sense for any $X$, and is called the indiscrete topology.

Comment: Ah yes, this was what my confusion was - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A topology on a set $X$ is by definition the data of all the open subsets of $X$ (which must satisfy a few properties, such as being stable by unions, etc).

On a given set $X$, you can put different topologies. This part discusses the different topologies you can put on $X=\{a,b\}$. "One could declare $\{a\}$ to be open" means that there is a topology on $X$ where $\{a\}$ is open.

Comment: I think I should clarify my confusion - why can we declare that $\{a\}$ is open and $\{b\}$ to not be open? Shouldn't the openness of a set be determined from the definition of openness (i.e. independent of how we define the topology)?

Comment: @SeanLee No, because the "sets that are open" is *precisely* what the topology is.

Comment: Oh so this is a completely different kind of "openness" as compared to the "A set $U$ is open if there is a neighborhood $\delta > 0$ around any point $x \in U$ such that $B_\delta (x) \subset U $" definition?

Comment: Not completely different: that definition is one example of a topology, out of many possible topologies (a particularly useful one on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and other metric spaces).

Answer (score 0):

A topology on a set $X$ is given by any family $\cal T$ of subsets of $X$, such that whenever $A_i \in \cal T$ for all $i$ in some index set $I$, then $\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)\in \cal T$ and whenever $A\in \cal T$ and $B \in \cal T$, then $(A \cap B) \in \cal T$. (In words, $\cal T$ is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections.) The elements of $\cal T$ are called open sets, or open sets with respect to $\cal T$. There is no presupposition here that $\cal T$ is defined in terms of some other structure on $X$ (although it might be, e.g., it might be defined using a metric on $X$ and declaring $\cal T$ to be open if it is a union of open balls).

So, for example, if $X = \{a, b\}$, where $a$ and $b$ are some distinct objects and you define ${\cal T} = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, X\}$, you can verify that $\cal T$ is a topology under the above definition and that $\{a\}$ is open with respect to $\cal T$ but $\{b\}$ is not: the only open set that has $b$ as a member is $X$. This particular example cannot arise from a metric on $X$.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally many different topologies on any set. Each topology uses a different meaning of whether or not a set is open, in the context of that topology.

You may be thinking of open sets in the Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$, with a definition like "a set $U$ is open if for every $x \in U$ there exists a positive real number $\delta$ so that the ball at $x$ with radius $\delta$ is a subset of $U$", or an equivalent statement. But that description is what we call the *standard* open sets in the *standard* topology for $\mathbb{R}^n$. $\mathbb{R}^n$ has plenty of other topologies: We can say "only the empty set and all $\mathbb{R}^n$ are open" to get the "trivial topology" as if all points are very close together. We can say "all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are open" to get the "discrete topology" as if all points are very far apart.

In this example, the set of elements isn't related at all to $\mathbb{R}^n$. It's just a set of two elements. What definition would you even use to decide whether $\{a\}$ is open? (It's true the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has no open sets with exactly one element, but that's a consequence of a property of $\mathbb{R}$, and doesn't apply here.) The point seems to be to consider all the possible topologies on a set with two elements, and realize there are exactly four of them. Each has a different set of open subsets, just because that's what a topology is.